# Get current workspace from inside a AzureML Pipeline step

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I'm using the Python SDK.

I assume there is a way to get a handle to the workspace on which the `PythonScriptStep` is running from inside the `PythonScriptStep` but I can't find it.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

The way to get a handle to the current experiment workspace is the following:

```py
from azureml.core import Run


run = Run.get_context()
workspace = run.experiment.workspace
```

This is taken from the following example:
https://azure.github.io/azureml-cheatsheets/docs/cheatsheets/python/v1/logging/#logging-with-mlflow

Comment: glad you figured it out, and thanks for writing it up!

Comment: this works for azureml sdkv1 but not in azureml sdkv2 (azure.ai.ml). How might once get the workspace object, aka MLClient, inside a sdkv2 pipeline step?